# Full body workout spread throughout the day?

Tags: weightlifting

Stressed for time, I figured I could use my work breaks to get in some strength/weight workouts.

My idea is to use the short breaks to do one workout every break.

Example: Two minute deadlift specific warmup, then deadlift 4 Sets, 10 Reps.

Since the anaerobic stress isn't that hard, I would probably not "break a sweat" and not need to shower afterwards.

I do about four short breaks, so I would have four workouts a day.

Spread this over the week and probably use a split (push/pull/legs) and I would have quite a good overall volume.

What could be a problem with this idea?
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea works. The only thing people may need to consider is how much each individual needs to warm up, and time to set up each exercise.
Hypertrophy for a muscle group may be lower then if multiple exercise is performed in a closer succession due to the decreased density of work being performed each break you have.

Depending on exercise choice (more than just doing an exercise once a week) you can get stronger or be able to perform more reps over time. This is due to improving neurological efficiencies and improve technique.

Pavel Tsatsouline describes something similar in  Power to the People as “greasing the grove”. In his example a person would do a submaximal number of pull-ups in the doorway every time they passed the door.